# execute update or insert query to multiple databases at same time by using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, multiple-databases

I use `date("h:i:s")` for example. I've tried to execute the update query against multiple databases at same time, but the time could be different 1 or 2 seconds or maybe more, depends on the update process from one database to the others. I knew, my coding wouldn't work because I used recursive function and it proceed the queries one by one. I wonder if there were another ways to execute it at same time without looping or proceed the queries to all databases at once..

this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function updateTimer() {
        var db = "1,2,",
        dbindex = db.split(","),
        countdb = 2;
        function retrieve(id) {
            if(id < countdb) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'update.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        idx : dbindex[id]-1
                    },
                    success: function (output) {
                        id++;
                        retrieve(id);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error Update");
                    }
                });
            }
         }
         retrieve(0);
      }
//-->
</script>
```

update.php

```
$idx = $_POST["idx"];
$conn = $db[$index[$idx]]; // testdb and test2db
$timer = date("h:i:s");
mysqli_query($conn,"update table set timer='".$timer."'");
```